# Ошибка в коде js при котором некорректно работает alert

Tags: javascript, link

Почему в видеоуроке от **mail.ru** написано `$('a').click(function() {alert('lalala'); return false;});` и при нажатии на ссылку выскакивает alert и после нажатия на ок не пропускает дальше пользователя, при повторном нажатии на ссылку выскакивает alert

А в моем коде `<div class="header__list_raw" onclick="userIsntLogged ();"></div>`

**js**

```
function  userIsntLogged () {
    alert('Для начала войдите на сайт');
    return false;
    }
```

При нажатии на ссылку открывает alert после нажатия на ок переходит на ссылку, при повторном нажатии на ссылку alert не выскакивает, пока не обновишь страницу

Comment: Потому что `onclick="return userIsntLogged()"`. Но вообще не нужно так писать.

Comment: А я чот не понял на какую такую "ссылку" переходишь по нажатию на `div` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы по разному устанавливаете обработчик события.

```
$('a').click(function() {alert('lalala'); return false;});

<div class="header__list_raw" onclick="userIsntLogged ();"></div>
```

В первом случае вешается обработчик события на клик по ссылке и внутри возвращается `false` дабы остановить всплытие и поведение по умолчанию. У вас же при клике выполняется функция, которая тоже возвращает `false`, но есть одно **НО**

Ваш код `js` выполняет примерно вот так

```
<div onclick="function(event) { userIsntLogged (); }">
</div>
```

То есть на самом деле `js` оборачивает ваш код в функцию. Что бы работало, нужно что бы именно эта "нативная" ф-ция возвращала `false`

```
<div onclick="userIsntLogged (); return false">
</div>

// либо
<div onclick="return userIsntLogged ();">
</div>
```

P.S. 
Возвращать `false` уже не модно, это слишком неявный способ, потому что кроме отмены действия по умолчанию он еще и останавливает всплытие. Используйте лучше `stopPropogation`, `preventDefault`

```
<div onclick="userIsntLogged (event);">
</div>

function  userIsntLogged (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // отменяем всплытие
    e.preventDefault(); // отменяем действие по умолчанию
    alert('Для начала войдите на сайт');
}
```

Comment: Теперь работает, спасибо